# Half Derivatives in Maxima

Tags: fractional-calculus, maxima-software

Is it possible to take the half derivative of a function in maxima? I tried the following:

```
(%i1) g: x^3;
                                       3
(%o1)                                 x
(%i2) diff (g, x, 1/2);
                                   1/2
                                  d       3
(%o2)                             ----- (x )
                                    1/2
                                  dx
```

It does not seem to compute it. Is there any possible way to calculate this in maxima? Furthermore, is it also possible to take the half integral in some way?

Comment: There is a lot of notions of fractional derivatives (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Fractional+calculus&title=Special:Search&ns0=1)). What of those do you have in mind?